# Why it is allowed to index array with invalid keys in mapped object

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, tuples, mapped-types

In the [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZygENsQBtAXQD4oBeKAbwCgooyBpKAS2ymTOwBXALYAjCACcKFKAC4+HCkwC+TJgHoAVCyihIUdHUY7WrACzzBeCADMeEXAG4Tp4HADKwCTwDm8gBQAlHQ0+F6+zqamRKIAxriW2ADW2HAA7tiRUVAAjPIARDHx+VmqmupMetCG9PBIZADkbp7e2D4NADRQDUW4nbldZtQa2qxVUCBGzFFk6PJhrT4UiSnpmTplFeOTtQiIZAu+w1o64wBeUy6z8kJikstQt+ISpUzlleDQF7v1T-dUI1OnygABsppsPvowT99vgQGI4CDjqNdMCbOC3ls0UY6vsAAoSODCLj4CCIP4SKjUIA) typescript compiler allows us to index tuple with invalid keys infering `unknown` for invalid string keys and `undefined` for invalid number keys. When indexing with an object like `Promise<number>` tsc infers empty object.

```
type Foo<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in T[number]] : T[K]
}

/*
  type x = {
      4: undefined;
      toString: () => string;
      abcd: unknown;
      1: "abcd";
  }
*/
type x = Foo<['toString', 'abcd', 1, 4]>
/*
  type y = {
    [x: string]: unknown;
  }
*/
type y = Foo<[string]>
/*
  type z = {
    [x: number]: number;
  }
*/
type z = Foo<[number]>
/*
  type l = {}
*/
type l = Foo<[symbol]>
/*
  type f = {}
*/
type f = Foo<[Promise<number>]>
```

Why is this allowed? Why removing `extends any[]` bound produces compile error, that I would expect to see without removing it.